# VBA: Adding class items to a collection within class

Tags: vba, class, collections

I'm trying to make a tree (kind of a composite pattern actually), but I just can't add the created items of a class to a collection of items in the parent.

Inside the class

```
Private pChildList As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pChildList = New Collection
End Sub

Public Property Set ChildList(Value As CProduct)
    pChildList.Add Value
End Property

Public Property Get ChildList() As Collection
    ChildList = pChildList
End Property
```

The main function calling

```
Set Pro = New CProduct
Set Child = New CProduct
Pro.ChildList.Add Child
```

So the result should be a parent (Pro) with a Child in its pChildList collection, but I only get the error that "Argument is not optional".

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just missing a `Set` in your property Get definition. A `Collection` is an object, you need to use the `Set` keyword to affect it to a variable.

```
Public Property Get ChildList() As Collection
    Set ChildList = pChildList
End Property
```

To complement my answer following you comment:

`Property Set` are for Objects, `Property Let` are for base types. Those two properties are usually used to change the value of a member variable (and are expected to do that), that is to access the variable for writing, but you can do whatever you want in the code.
`Property Get` are usually used to return the value of a member variable (but once again, you can do whatever you want in code), that is to access the variable for reading.
Since there is no reason to change the pChildList itself, I would drop totally the `Property Set`.
You can also decide to completely hide the member variable and use member functions to add and remove Childs, for example:

```
Public Sub AddChild(vValue as CProduct)
    pChildList.Add vValue
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! What I don't get now neither before when stepping through the code is why it's using the "Get" function anyway? I'm trying to set (or add actually) an Item to pChildList, does the program need to first return the collection to the main function and add the item there before returning the new collection to the class or what's the deal?

Comment: Well, the code is doing what you tell it to do when you wrote `Pro.ChildList.Add Child`. You could also have written `Set Pro.ChildList = Child` to do the same (given the code yo wrote, note that the `Set` property you wrote is odd and doesn't do what it could be expected to do).

Comment: If I'm honest I only made the Set function because "Let" that I use for the other variables gave me an error, it said I only could use "get, let or set" and set didn't gave me any error. So what would be the preffered way of returning/accessing the pChildList outside the class?